# import error in celeryd task

Tags: python, django, celery

I am having problems running my celery task because it cannot find one of my modules:

```
(ff)bash-3.2$ flipfinder_app/manage.py celeryd
[...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 248, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 97, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 268, in worker
initializer(*initargs)
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/__init__.py", line 51, in process_initializer
app.loader.init_worker()
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 115, in init_worker
self.import_default_modules()
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py", line 136, in import_default_modules
super(DjangoLoader, self).import_default_modules()
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 110, in import_default_modules
| self.builtin_modules]
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 96, in import_task_module
return self.import_from_cwd(module)
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 104, in import_from_cwd
package=package)
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 96, in import_from_cwd
return imp(module, package=package)
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 99, in import_module
return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app/apps/tabs/keywords/tasks.py", line 11, in <module>
from apps.util.adsense import has_adsense
ImportError: No module named adsense
```

It does exist:

```
(ff)bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app/apps/util
(ff)bash-3.2$ ls | grep adsense
adsense.py
```

And when I use the django shell, it imports fine.

```
(ff)bash-3.2$ ff_app/manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  9 2013, 09:25:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from apps.util.adsense import has_adsense
>>> has_adsense
<function has_adsense at 0x10d3171b8>
```

I added this to the task file:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

and see this output when I try to run celery:

```
['/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app', '/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app/lib',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app/apps', '/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app/lib',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app/apps', '/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/src/pywhois', '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/src/django-filter',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.5.0.103',
 '/Users/jasonlfunk/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

You can see that `/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app` is in the path which is where the import should be.

I aslo added this to the tasks file:

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app')
```

And everything works fine.

```
 -------------- celery@Jason-Funks-MacBook-Pro.local v3.0.11 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      django://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- . app:         default:0x10ddf5810 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 2 (processes)
- ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
- ** ---------- 
- *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** ----- 

[2013-01-16 17:22:53,248: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Jason-Funks-MacBook-Pro.local ready.
```

What's going on? Why does cd'ing into a directory that is already in my path fix the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `from apps.util.adsense import has_adsense` with `from ff_app.apps.util.adsense import has_adsense`?

Comment: Didn't help:
`File "/Users/jasonlfunk/Workspace/Work/csm/ff-app/ff_app/apps/tabs/keywords/tasks.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ff_app.apps.util.adsense import has_adsense
ImportError: No module named apps.util.adsense`

Comment: I alsho have the same problem , please somebody help

Answer (score 0):

Is **from apps.util.adsense import has_adsense** inside task def ?